# Где получать данные по штрафам на машину бесплатный способ

Tags: php, api

Скажите, есть ли еще бесплатные способы получать штрафы на машины, например есть парк, два десятка машин. хотелось бы по ним отслеживать наличие штрафов, оперативно, хотябы раз в день проверять.

Искал API, нашел минимум 3 сервиса, но они естественно платные, ну там для 1-2 машин дадут бесплатно получить, но для 20 платно. Просят от 2 до 5 тр в месяц.

Нашел API гибдд, но похоже оно закрыто, скорее всего с целью (мое предположение) зарабатывания денег на платных API.

Я даже готов не по API, а например подписка на штрафы на электронную почту, а почту я уже разберу скриптом.

Вобщем очень хотелось бы найти бесплатное решение.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, знатоки.

Comment: *очень хотелось бы найти бесплатное решение* На портале госуслуг - по номеру В/У и/или СТС. Через мобильное приложение - практически в режиме реального времени. https://www.gosuslugi.ru/10001/1

Comment: ну мне так, чтоб можно было спарсить, я по этому и говорил, например на почту, я там распарсю скриптом. а приложение я врядли смогу. или там как то можно тоже на почту настроить?

Comment: Что, закачать приложение да посмотреть - слишком трудно, только спрашивать умеем? И да - оповещение на почту там есть, искать в настройках ЛК.

Comment: приложение то какое? госуслуги?

Comment: подскажите как настроить штрафы на почту? я вижу штрафы, показывает в приложении, но на почту ничего не пришло

Comment: Я же вроде вменяемо сказал - настроить уведомления в личном кабинете своего профиля на портале госуслуг... https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOh88.png

Comment: А это разве сайт госуслуг? Написано сайт мера москвы. У меня кстати не московский регион

Comment: плюсанул вопрос, тоже скоро понадобится подобный функционал, недавно бегло поискал, толкового ничего не нашел. Относительно API гибдд возможно оно и есть, а вот документация скрыта, и платные сервисы, его и используют. Тут где то были похожие вопросы, но очень древние и не актуальные. Но мне бы желательно именно какой-то API функционал, свободный.

Comment: *А это разве сайт госуслуг?* Это ГОСУСЛУГА. И какая разница, через какую калитку её получать? Всё равно авторизация идёт на ЕЛК, а там уж всё зависит от того, через что ты придёшь. Я вот на авторизацию прихожу с сайта Мосуслуг, который теперь превратили в сайт мэра - потому и после авторизации попадаю обратно на него. В мобильном приложении я авторизуюсь в ЕЛК напрямую. Ты авторизуешься иначе... Но ни сама услуга, ни её сервисы от этого не изменятся. И пофиг регион.

Answer (score 1):

Более 4 лет работаю в сфере, где нужны данные по штрафам и вот к чему пришёл:

1. Абсолютно бесплатного варианта кроме госуслуг нет. Но у них нет возможности удобно выгрузить штрафы куда либо.
2. Если вас интересуют только штрафы ГИБДД и не нужны штрафы ФССП, МАДИ, АМПП, тогда можете брать данные с сайта ГИБДД напрямую. На данный момент (март 2020 года) там стоит Google reCAPTCHA. Можете выбрать любой сервис для решения reCAPTCHA и напрямую брать данные с ГИБДД.

Правда есть несколько минусов:

- На сайте ГИБДД иногда происходят изменения и вам придётся адаптировать своё решение.
- При формировании бюджета для сервиса решения reCAPTCHA стоит иметь ввиду тот факт, что до 100% процентов токенов могут быть неработоспособны, но за них все равно придётся платить.

Но с учетом минусов есть и плюс - это всё равно ГОРАЗДО дешевле, чем существующие парсеры.

3. Если вас смущают минусы предыдущего решения, то можете использовать готовые парсеры. Например [api-parser.ru](http://api-parser.ru) и [gibdd-api.mchanges.com](http://gibdd-api.mchanges.com). Но цены кусаются.
4. Если вам нужны все виды штрафов (и фотографии), то придётся использовать специальные сервисы, которые вы сами нашли. Зато есть api, выгрузка в excel и многие другие удобства. Например, у сервиса [Твоя ГИБДД](https://ygibdd.ru/Business/Promo) минимальный тариф 1000 рублей, что в два раза меньше чем у [api-parser.ru](http://api-parser.ru).

Если кому интересно, есть еще пара сервисов-гигантов: штрафов нет и онлайн гибдд.

Также думаю, что с любым из этих сервисов можно договориться и получить доступ к их парсеру ГИБДД. Думаю, будет дешевле, чем у парсеров из пункта 3. Попробуйте написать в поддержку и уточнить при желании.

Обновлено (ноябрь 2020). У сервиса Твоя ГИБДД теперь есть [парсер](https://ygibdd.ru/Parser/Gibdd). Но он работает только 80% времени. Зато дешёвый. В основном использую его, но если сбоит, то переключаюсь на api-parser.ru. Получается дёшево и сердито.

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатных сервисов нет, все зарабатывают деньги.
Я пользуюсь этим сервисом [проверки штрафов](https://www.driver-helper.ru/shtrafy-gibdd/proverit) АПИ конечно у них нет, но письма на email они присылают вовремя. И ничего не надо адаптировать.